# How do I add add device timestamp when ion-checkbox is set to true

Tags: ionic2

I am presently using check boxes to track when tasks have been completed in my ionic 2 App.  Is there a way save the date/time from the mobile device when this checkbox is selected.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Task 1</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.task1"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>    
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) from Javascript to do so, like you can see in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wEnK78?p=preview).

Your `Component`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
     templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  public data: any;
  public dateTime : string = '';

  constructor() {
    this.data = {
      task1 : false
    }
  }

  public changeCheckBox() {
    if(this.data.task1) {
      this.dateTime = new Date();
    }
  }
}
```

Your view:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Task 1</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.task1" (ionChange)="changeCheckBox()"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>  
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Timestamp: {{ dateTime }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Of course you can obtain detailed information by using some of the get methods:

```
Date.prototype.getDate()
Date.prototype.getDay()
Date.prototype.getFullYear()
Date.prototype.getHours()
Date.prototype.getMilliseconds()
Date.prototype.getMinutes()
Date.prototype.getMonth()
Date.prototype.getSeconds()
Date.prototype.getTime()
Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()
Date.prototype.getUTCDate()
Date.prototype.getUTCDay()
Date.prototype.getUTCFullYear()
Date.prototype.getUTCHours()
Date.prototype.getUTCMilliseconds()
Date.prototype.getUTCMinutes()
Date.prototype.getUTCMonth()
Date.prototype.getUTCSeconds()
Date.prototype.getYear()
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to play with this a bit.

Comment: Glad I could help :)